# Printing Number Lines in C

Tags: c, numbers, lines

I try to read a file then print the number lines with them. But I don't know how can I print the lorem ipsum in the same time. Because I don't know much about printing functions in C.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(){

int c;
int b=1;
//int a[5000]; Shall I use this or any ideas without them?

FILE *xfile;
xfile = fopen("loremipsum.txt", "r"); 

while((c=getc(xfile)) != EOF){
if(c == '\n'){
printf("%d\n", b); /*STUCK IN THERE... HOW TO PRINT LOREM IPSUM WITH NUMBER LINES?*/
//putchar(a);   
b++;
}
}

}
```

My lorem ipsum:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec vitae quam non risus consectetur aliquet sed rhoncus purus.
Fusce vitae lorem a dui elementum condimentum id id odio.
Quisque eu felis eu diam facilisis mollis sit amet id augue.


Duis lacinia velit et lorem ullamcorper iaculis.
Duis malesuada lacus quis quam congue nec euismod ante condimentum.
Donec dignissim augue vitae nulla dapibus vehicula.
```

What I want:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2. Donec vitae quam non risus consectetur aliquet sed rhoncus purus.
3. Fusce vitae lorem a dui elementum condimentum id id odio.
4. Quisque eu felis eu diam facilisis mollis sit amet id augue.


5. Duis lacinia velit et lorem ullamcorper iaculis.
6. Duis malesuada lacus quis quam congue nec euismod ante condimentum.
7. Donec dignissim augue vitae nulla dapibus vehicula.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `fgets` instead, to get whole lines instead of reading one character at a time?

```
char input[256];
int line = 1;

while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), xfile) != NULL)
{
    printf("%2d. %s", line++, input);
}
```

Comment: Just make sure the lines in the file aren't longer than input or you could get wrong results.

Answer (score 3):

You have the good method, although it could be useful to keep the last character in a variable.

```
int c;
int b = 1;
int prec = '\n';

while ((c = getc (xfile)) != EOF) {
        if (prec == '\n')
                printf ("%d. ", b++);

        putchar (c);
        prec = c;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a good answer since it handler files ending in `\n`.

Comment: @cnicutar  ..For OP I want to print last `\n` so he come to know about difference. Kirilenko answer is nice..but you answer was good too I voted you.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks, I appreciate it but I was already capped for the day and my answer didn't really add anything to the thread.